# How to I cut a wav file based on time segments?

Tags: python, wav

I have a wav file that I need to split up using the following list:

```
[0.89, 1.38, 1.945, 2.93, 3.435, 4.47, 5.435, 6.035, 6.67, 7.665, 8.48]
```

I want to create an array of smaller wav files that are the following segments from the original wav file:

```
0.89 to (1.38 - 0.05) 
1.38 to (1.945 - 0.05)
```

Is there a way to do that? I've googled it but it seems like the wave library only does it for bytes, not the timing.

Comment: I think you should look into wav file formats, the header contains the data you need to be able to grab bytes [Wav File Format Tutorial Thing](http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the wave module documentation:

Wave_read.getsampwidth()

```
Returns sample width in bytes.
```

Wave_read.getframerate()

```
Returns sampling frequency.
```

Using those you should be able to calculate the bytes per second of your file.

Comment: This could work. I'm not able to actually chunk the wav file but I can now read what I need. Thanks!